# value of an option appended to a select ends with " before the fetched value ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fetching some data using ajax from my database, the problem is when I append an option to a select with a value containing these data, the append ends the first word with " thus the rest is left outside the value tag.

Here's the empty select:

```
<select name="Sender" id="SenderNames" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;"></select>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$('#SenderSelect').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'operations/inner-operations/getNamesByService.php',
        data: { action :"getService", "serviceName" : $("#SenderSelect option:selected").val() },
        success: function(data) {
            var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(responseObj);
            $.each(responseObj, function(i, value) {
                $("#SenderNames").append('<option value='+value+'>'+value+'</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The appended option should look like this:

```
<option value="First Second">First Second</option>
```

However, it is appended like this:

```
<option value="First" second="">First Second</option>
```

Comment: There are no double quotes in the HTML your JS generates.  The HTML you show can't have been generated by your code.  That could suggest that the double quotes are in the content coming back from your AJAX call ... so what gives? Is that really your generated HTML?  What does your AJAX response look like?

Comment: @Don'tPanic you're correct, I must wrap the value with double quotes, that's why HTML added its own double quotes for the first word and considered the second as a tag.

Comment: Are viewing the generated HTML in Chrome devtools?  I have noticed it tends to add things like quotes etc when they are not really present in the HTML, maybe that's what you were seeing, which would have confused the issue.  Well done for finding it.

Comment: I'm using Chrome inspection, I had to actually copy the element to see the changes. The Chrome inspection doesn't show that the second word is actually considered a tag(with the = and "").

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that I'm not closing the string properly. The append should be like this:

```
$("#SenderNames").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
```

the value tag must be wrapped by "".